# What is the c++ approach for upgrading these c style casts for HtmlHelp API?

Tags: c++, mfc, html-help

What is the c++ approach for upgrading these c style casts for `HtmlHelp` API?

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::DisplayHelpTopic(CString strTopic)
{
    CString strURL = _T("https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/") + strTopic;

    if (theApp.UseDownloadedHelpDocumentation())
    {
        // CHM files use 3 letter suffix
        strTopic.Replace(_T(".html"), _T(".htm"));
        HtmlHelp((DWORD_PTR)(LPCTSTR)strTopic, HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);
    }
    else
        ShellExecute(nullptr, nullptr, strURL, nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}
```

Specifically:

`HtmlHelp((DWORD_PTR)(LPCTSTR)strTopic, HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);`

---

In answer to the question in the comments:

[image]

It is odd because the official docs for x86 [`HtmlHelpA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/htmlhelp/nf-htmlhelp-htmlhelpa?redirectedfrom=MSDN&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(HTMLHELP%252FHtmlHelp);k(HtmlHelp);k(DevLang-C%252B%252B);k(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue) / [`HtmlHelpW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/htmlhelp/nf-htmlhelp-htmlhelpw) do indicate different calls.

It doesn't seem to be listed as part of the `CWinApp` class in the docs.

Comment: Isn't the `HtmlHelp` call missing two parameters?

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is how my app has fired the help for years. Works every time. So I don't need to add any new paramaters. Just to update the way the casting is done.

Comment: This is typical Windows stuff. Best to stick with the idioms that were formed thirty years ago.

Comment: @PeteBecker So leave it as it is and add a pragma suppression

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Can you click on `HtmlHelp` and _go to definition_ to see what the definition actually is? Is it a macro? If so, to what?

Comment: `HtmlHelp` has been overridden either in a MFC class or one of the application base classes of `CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp`  So I think there is no point in recommending any "fix" until we see the actual function signature.  The first parameter of the Win32API version of `HtmlHelp` is a (optional) `HWND` see - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/htmlhelp/nf-htmlhelp-htmlhelpa

Comment: @RichardCritten not overridden but either class has the method HtmlHelp. Having a method is not overriding or overloading a free function.

Comment: @S.M. you are right bad choice of language. Just out of time for an edit.

Comment: My biggest bet right now is on `reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(strTopic))` - but seeing the definition of `HtmlHelp` would ... help

Comment: @S.M. I wouldn't call function-style casts _better_. They do exactly the same as the C style casts so I doubt those will get rid of the warnings. The explicit casts are generally considered _better_. "_The functional cast expression ... is exactly equivalent to the corresponding C-style cast expression._" [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: @S.M. I'm wrong about a lot of things. Which thing is it this time? :-)

Comment: @S.M. Because it tells the compiler that that is exactly what you want, so the warning is removed. I also used a `static_cast` where I _think_ it's appropriate. Even if I used `reinterpret_cast` in both places it's better because it tells the compiler and a reader of the code that, yes, I do want this brute cast.

Comment: @Ted you tell the same with using function style casts.

Comment: @S.M. Sorry, I don't understand. A function-style cast is exactly the same as a C style cast. It doesn't provide any more information than the C style cast - which is what generates the warning. Perhaps a functions-style cast _is_ enough to make the warning go away - but it doesn't tell a reader of the code (human or machine) anything more than the C style cast does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `reinterpret_cast` will always trigger a code analysys warning

In that case, you could invent your own pointer cast function. A smart compiler will most probably optimize this away:

```
#include <cstring>

template<class D, class T>
D ptr_cast(T* x) {
    D rv;
    static_assert(sizeof rv == sizeof x);
    std::memcpy(&rv, &x, sizeof rv);
    return rv;
}
```

Then

```
HtmlHelp( ptr_cast<DWORD_PTR>(strTopic.GetString()),
          HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);
```

---

In g++ and clang++, explicitly instantiating the function

```
template DWORD_PTR ptr_cast<DWORD_PTR,char>(char*);
```

makes it into the assembly code

```
unsigned long ptr_cast<unsigned long, char>(char*):
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

When inlined and optimized (as it will be in your code) the function call is gone and only the `mov` (assignment) to the destination `DWORD_PTR` is left, which is exactly the trace a `reinterpret_cast` would leave. In MSVC, inlining it results in the similar:

```
lea     rdx, OFFSET FLAT:`string'
```

Comment: I have had suggested before about using pointer cast templates and I think we came acropper. But that was for specific situations in my app. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You're welcome! Did you try it to see if it solved the problem?

Comment: Works well, thanks.

Comment: @Ted Interesting, how do you, can we change the used compiler clang++, g++, msvc in vs on the fly? I never used this before.

Comment: @TomTom No, I used https://godbolt.org/  to check the assembler for the different compilers.

Answer (score 1):

`(LPCTSTR)strTopic` calls `CString::operator LPCTSTR()`. Then `(DWORD_PTR)` converts pointer LPCTSTR to DWORD_PTR. There is no possible direct conversion from CString object to DWORD_PTR due to different source and target sizes.

C++ type casts can be the same short length as C type casts

```
HtmlHelp(DWORD_PTR(LPCTSTR(strTopic)), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);
```

---

MFC CWnd and CWinApp classes have the methods, that get the first parameter of the type DWORD_PTR

```
virtual void HtmlHelp(
    DWORD_PTR dwData,
    UINT nCmd = 0x000F);
```

Comment: I see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#htmlhelp

Comment: So it is a catch 22. Using reinterpret cast will trigger a code analysis too.

Comment: I understand that the `(LPCTSTR)` cast can be avoided my usting `strTopic.GetString();`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle So you get a warning for both `reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(strTopic))` and `reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(strTopic.GetString())` too then?

Comment: reinterpret_cast will always trigger a code analysys warning. So either way I have to add a praga.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you may use `strTopic.GetString()`.